# Connection to Exchange with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, exchangewebservices

I'm creating an app that needs to connect to Exchange and retrieve information. Is there an easy way to connect to Exchange Web Services from the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can Use EWS, EAS, or OWA for Exchange service.

1)if you want o use OWA service, check the below link,you will get wrapper class for OWA exchange.

https://github.com/jgallen23/OWAParser

2)EWS

For Ews i converted Services.wsdl(Describes the contract between client and server) to objetiveC using sudzc and made changes in Sudzc generated code.

Check below links also

// request for read mail

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa566107(v=exchg.140).aspx

// request for get folder list

/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa564829(v=exchg.140).aspx

3)EAS

i hope below lnik will be helpful for EAS exchange developement. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2011/09/28/new-to-exchange-activesync-development.aspx

Comment: Now i don't have the sample code. Do with EWS, Its not much difficult.
Check EWS steps that  i mentioned in answer.

Comment: EWS works over NTLM right? but didRecieveChanllenge delegate is not  calling the NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM. First time it is sending the challenge for serverTrust and second time for Basic. After that it is returning the data.

Comment: That's why I wanted to check your code, if I am missing anything or not